AG grid limit the number of rows shown for a given data point with filtering
I have an implementation of grid with external filters, and I am trying to allow another external filter to 'limit the number of rows shown for each data point in a specific column'.
For example, if I have a column that is userId, and i want to show the top 5 grades (different column) for each user id, how would i accomplish this?
I think it would be fairly easy to do with manipulating the data, but that would not take into account the filters that I have applied via external filters.
I could run all of my filter logic outside of externalFilterPass (aka manipulate the filters and data all at once via rowData filtering) but i fear for performance losses there.
Using React for what it's worth. I'm hoping there is an elegant way to deal with this that I haven't thought of yet
